# JavaScript : XPathEvaluator not supported in IE

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xpath, bookmarklet

I have the following function in `JavaScript`, and it fails to run when using `Internet Explorer`.

This function extract the value from a `HTML tag`, if a `XPath` is supplied.

How can i replace this function, and with what ?

```
function lookupElementByXPath(path) {
    var evaluator = new XPathEvaluator(); 
    var result = evaluator.evaluate(path, document.documentElement, null,XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null); 
    return result.singleNodeValue;
}
```