# Javascript:XPathEvaluator() is undefined

Tags: javascript

I`m using "XPathEvaluator" builtin function in js file,but it throws error like

```
  "'XPathEvaluator' is undefined".
```

I have added code like ->

```
  var Evalt = new XPathEvaluator();
  var luate = Evalt.evaluate(path,ss,sd,null);
```

What is the problem here?Have I missed any namespaces/library?
I`m using IE 8.
Please suggest some answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript : XPathEvaluator not supported in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927990/javascript-xpathevaluator-not-supported-in-ie) The problem sadly is IE8.

Comment: And duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402111/how-to-access-html-element-using-xpath-in-ie8

Answer (score 0):

This actual error is...

```
ReferenceError: 'XPathEvaluator' is undefined
```

As per the article, [Resolving the Error "XPathEvaluator’ is undefined"](https://www.qgate.co.uk/knowledge/resolving-the-error-xpathevaluator-is-undefined/) this *XPathEvaluator is undefined* script error is often observed in *Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011* after upgrading to [internet-explorer-11](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-11). Further investigation revealed, any HTML resource that includes `ClientGlobalContext.js` (which is used to get the context of the parent form) will throw the error the error `SCRIPT5009: ‘XPathEvaluator’ is undefined`.

---

### Solution

The solution is to add the following line to the `<head>` of your custom HTML documents that reference that particular *JS* file:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

This this line of the *script* is to force the browser to run the web resource in [internet-explorer-10](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-10) mode.

> **Caution**: The downside is that this functionality will be depreciated in [microsoft-edge](/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge), which is Microsoft’s newly released *Internet Explorer* replacement.