# User suddenly getting "XPath Evaluator is Undefined" error

Tags: internet-explorer, xpath, html

This is an issue coming from a user of a system I support. The system is a web-based enterprise application. I should note that I am *not* the developer for it. The reason why I am not asking their support for this is because their previous support has been "We don't need to fix that, we just choose not to support it", and I honestly doubt anyone less than one of their devs would understand the issue.

A user is attempting to access a function in this webpage (specifically, they are attempting to create an entry for a business engagement). This function generates a new window that is used to create this new thing, with multiple tabs along the side to access different sections. While the window does open properly, and with the tabs present even, the default 'General' tab's page is blank and a popup saying "XPath Evaluator is Undefined" appears in the middle. The window is unresponsive beyond closing that error message.

The user had IE 10, upgraded to IE 11, and downgraded back down to IE 10 with it working. She says she installed Skype right before it stopped functioning, but didn't get it to work again after she uninstalled Skype. No cache clears or reboots have helped her. I have been unable to recreate the problem using every browser under the sun on my machine:

- Firefox 33 + FireIE*
- Firefox 31 + FireIE*
- IE 11
- IE 10**
- IE 9**
- IE 8**
- IE 7**
- IE 6**
- Firefox**
- Chrome**
- Opera**

*FireIE is a FF add-on that basically emulates IE in Firefox. I had it force IE 10 standards.

**IE 11's dev emulation.

The issue is that something on her workstation has made the webpage's code suddenly throw up an error. Any ideas on what broke, why it broke, and maybe a possible way to fix it? Chronologically speaking, Skype seems to be the culprit, and I am no stranger to Skype randomly breaking random programs, but I honestly have no idea how Skype could possibly break a web application like this. I have not been able to find what code appears to be breaking in my debug consoles either. Heck, I couldn't even figure out which version of XPath was being used.

Edit: Managed to grab the code that *appears* to be causing the issue:

```
function getSelectXMLNodes(doc, path) { 
    var xpath = new XPathEvaluator(); 
    var result = xpath.evaluate(path, doc, doc.createNSResolver(doc.documentElement), XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);  

    var nodeList = new Array(result.snapshotLength); 

    for (var i = 0; i < result.snapshotLength; i++) { 
        nodeList[i] = result.snapshotItem(i); 
    } 
    xpath = null; 
    result = null; 
    return nodeList; 
}
```

Comment: Are you able to run it on her machine (Remote Desktop or something) and look at the debug console when the error occurs? Also, it's not clear, under what version of IE is the error occurring for the user?

Comment: IE 10, and I was only able to get to the console after the window opens and the error is closed. But, we found that there is a workaround for her problem: having the debug open! As long as the debugging is started, the page can be navigated normally. The debug also crashed the webpage at every turn, but as long as I hit F12 after we have gotten to the page, the debugger works.

Comment: Does the error actually say that `XPath Evaluator` or `XPathEvaluator` is undefined? (is there a space or not?)

Comment: No space, actually. Makes sense with what I grabbed from the debug. In other news: double checked the removal of Skype to no avail. However, I was able to get Firefox+FireIE to work for her. So the code error is specific to IE. Which is odd, because that function's header (sorry I missed copying that) mentioned the code should only be used in non-IE browsers.

Comment: You might get helpful info from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411818/javascriptxpathevaluator-is-undefined and the duplicates linked to there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically what would have caused it to stop working at this time, but historically, IE has not supported XPathEvaluator.

According to [this post](http://p2p.wrox.com/book-professional-javascript-web-developers-2nd-edition-isbn-9780470227800/77381-javascript-xpath-when-xpathevaluator-fails.html), "You can use selectNode() and selectSingleNode() on the DOM Document object instead (IE only)."

Answer (score 0):

need to to change compatible mode as IE 10

just  have to  add this line in Head

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

clear cache the browser and try again! it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
ReferenceError: 'XPathEvaluator' is undefined
```

...implies that there was a *ReferenceError* while *XML processing* in *Javascript*.

In the the book *Professional Javascript for Web Developers* author @nzakas mentioned, [internet-explorer](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer) browser won't support `XPathEvaluator`. In this case users should use `selectNode()` and `selectSingleNode()` on the *DOM Document object* instead (for IE only).

---

### History

As per the article, [Resolving the Error "XPathEvaluator’ is undefined"](https://www.qgate.co.uk/knowledge/resolving-the-error-xpathevaluator-is-undefined/) this `XPathEvaluator is undefined` script error is often observed in *Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011* after upgrading to [internet-explorer-11](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-11). Further investigation revealed, any HTML resource that includes `ClientGlobalContext.js` (which is used to get the context of the parent form) will throw the error the error `SCRIPT5009: ‘XPathEvaluator’ is undefined`.

---

### Solution

The solution is to add the following line to the `<head>` of your custom HTML documents that reference that particular *JS* file:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

This this line of the *script* is to force the browser to run the web resource in [internet-explorer-10](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-10) mode.

> **Caution**: The downside is that this functionality will be depreciated in [microsoft-edge](/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge), which is Microsoft’s newly released *Internet Explorer* replacement.